# Enable Territory Management in Developer Edition

Tags: territory-management, support, territory

Is it possible to enable territory management in the free developer edition? This page (https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000175737) says this function is available "with the Enterprise, Unlimited and Developer Editions." The instructions tell me to open a case with salesforce.com to request territory management, but I am not allowed to submit a case with my free developer account.

Comment: You can raise a case from a developer edition.  Click the Help link and when the help portal opens, select the contact support option and you will then get an option to open a case.  There is a bug at the moment in the federated authentication for help that means if you are using my domain the help portal doesn't pick up your credentials and you have to login a bunch of times.  If you work for a partner you can raise a case through the partner portal and specify the organization id for your dev org.

Answer (score 3):

I think your best best would be to call Salesforce support directly to try to get this enabled.  As far as I know theres no way to use it without having support enable it for you.  Someone please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are correct. Just raise a case and support will enable it.